# Java Regex: Add quotes to start and end of string if missing

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a simple regex to add double quotes `"` to the begining or end of a string if these are infact mising using the `Java` `string.replaceAll` method.

So far, this is my best atempt:

```
string.replaceAll("(^[^\"])($)(?<!\")", "\"$1$2\"");
```

This works fine in isolation, but not together:

```
string.replaceAll("(^[^\"])", "\"$1");
string.replaceAll("($)(?<!\")", "$2\"");
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/u0GChO/1)

Could someone please indicate what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Chopo

Comment: Why do you need regex to achieve this?

Comment: @Biffen, `($)` should indicate end of string right?

Comment: @Prashant, why do you ask, would something like `if(!s.endsWith(...)...)...` give better performance? - Regex tend to give nice concise code that does not distract from the main purpose and logic of a method

Comment: @Chopo87 You are right but this is a very simple use case that does not need complex regex to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `(^[^\"])($)(?<!")`, you match any char other than `"` at the start of the string and you require the end of string to appear right after this char, and then you perform an additional check that the char is not a `"` (so, the lookbehind at the end is totally redundant).

If you need to add `"` at the start *or* end where the first / last char is not a `"`, you need to use an alternation:

```
s=s.replaceAll("^(?!\")|$(?<!\")", "\"");
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nTDYuf/1).

**Details**

- `^(?!\")` - match the start of string if there is no `"` at the start
- `|`  - or
- `$(?<!\")` - match the end of the string and check if there is a `"` at the end, fail if there is a `"` there.

**If you want to wrap the whole string with `"` if there are no `"`s around the string**, use

```
s=s.replaceFirst("(?s)^[^\"](?:.*[^\"])?$", "\"$0\"");
```

Or a simpler non-regex approach with string concatenation and a couple of `startsWith` and `endsWith`:

```
if (!s.endsWith("\"") && !s.startsWith("\"")) {
    System.out.println("\"" + s + "\"");
}
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/f7lHb1). The [pattern here](https://regex101.com/r/nTDYuf/2) means

- `(?s)^` - enable `Pattern.DOTALL` flag and match the start of the string
- `[^\"]` - any char other than `"`
- `(?:.*[^\"])?` - an optional sequence (what if a string has only 1 char?) of any 0+ chars and then any char other than `"`...
- `$` - at the end of the string.

The `$0` stands for the entire match value.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much @wiktor-stribizew